# Grid-like lines in my procedurally generated mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, mesh, procedural-generation

I have been working on my game for some time and I can't figure out why these lines are showing in my generated mesh.
I'm using multiple layers of perlin noise, each with a decreasing persistance and increasing level of detail. If you want more details about the actual code, I can provide, but it's pretty much the basic stuff that you find on any youtube tutorial about procedural terrain generation.

I put some screenshots below.
[img1](https://ibb.co/YcgRfJh), [img2](https://ibb.co/qJmbZyp), [img3](https://ibb.co/GthhBW8).

Could you please point me in the right direction with this, I feel like it's something really simple but I'm somehow missing it.

What I've tried: changing the material of the terrain, changing the lighting, playing with lacunarity/ persistance/ octaves. I get slightly different results from playing with the last 3 arguments (the lines repeat less or more often) but nothing that gets close to solving the problem.

Comment: There is not really enough information to go on without any code. My recommendation would be to generate a tiny part of your terrain, just a handful of triangles, so that you can step thru the code and inspect the generated mesh in the debugger. Stair-stepping *may* be the result of limited precision, see [the floating guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/), but there is no way to tell for sure without debugging. Writing unit tests that reproduce the issue might also be helpful to isolate and solve it.

Comment: if img2 is a sideways view the mesh looks to be the changing of heights slopes